# Как мне правильно отследить время?

Tags: php

Есть такая строка
`$c = "1h" или "1y 3h" или "1m";`

Ну вы поняли, в строке я могу указать время, часы, минуты, год.

Так вот, как мне отследить это время в time(), делаю бан систему.

Answer (score 0):

вам придется расшифровать h - hour, y - year ...

А потом можно воспользоваться [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php)

```
echo date('c') . "\n";                       // 2022-08-30T15:26:30+00:00
echo date('c', strtotime('+1year +1hour'));  // 2023-08-30T16:26:30+00:00
```